# What is this 2" Diameter Hole in Basement Foundation Floor?

Tags: basement, foundation, hole

I am wondering what this hole in my basement foundation floor is for, and if I can cover it up or just put a plug in it. I am aware of one other similar hole (carpet is covering it though) on the other side of the basement.

It appears to have a depth of about 1 foot and then turns. The house was built in 2000, if that matters.

[image]

Comment: Could you try running a plumbing snake into it and see how far it goes?

Comment: Looks like the den of an American Portland Lime-snake. Be careful; they can really damage any ceramics you might be storing in your basement.

Answer (score 1):

maybe i am missing something here, but isn't that a floor drain, just with no cover on it?

Comment: No proof, but that would be my guess.